# Keeping Static Header Over All Other Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, html-heading

I have a header in my index file defined as follows:

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="menu-trigger" class="header-button left icon-menu" ></div>
    <h1><a class='current' href="index.html#home">Title</a></h1>
</header>
```

I manage to get it static always at the top while scrolling with:

```
$(function() {
    console.log('Stick bar at top. . . ');
    // Stick the #nav to the top of the window
    var nav = $('#header');
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                left: nav.offset().left,
                width: nav.width(),
                //z-index: 1;
            });
            isFixed = true;
        }
        else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
        {
            nav.css({
                position: 'static'
            });
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that any views I load into the index.html file appear over the header. I need the header to be over all other elements.

Is there a way to do this ? Or should I be reloading the header after I reload all the views ?

Thanks,

Filipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS Propert z-index : 1000 should do that.

You can do it through class as well as through javascript/JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use a separate css file instead applying css modifiers with jQuery.

The `position:fixed` css modifier and with a high `z-index` value show do automatically what you are doing in the scroll handler.

By the way, you should never set the header back to `static`, `z-index` doesn't work with static boxes. If you need a space at the top, use `padding-top` or `margin-top` in the container element

Comment: You are right Nytramr. That method is simpler and works just as well.